# Descubrir complejidad algorítmica

Tags: python, complejidad

Necesito ayuda en analizar la notación asintótica del siguiente código.

Utilizo un solo `for`  y este seria O(N). Realizo varios cálculos dentro de él que supongo que son O(1). Lo que me tiene en duda si el `if` tambien es O(1) o este varia dependiendo la cantidad de `ifs` dentro.

Lo que realiza el código es buscar cadenas 'AAAA', 'TTTT', 'CCCC', o 'GGGG'. Estas pueden estar en forma horizontal, vertical o diagonal izquierda/derecha. Si se encuentran mas de 2 cadenas se hace un `return` y finaliza el `for`; si no, chequea la lista hasta la posicion `len(lista) - 3`.

Recibo una lista de tipo = ['A', 'C', ... , 'T'] que su largo no puede ser menor a 16.

Este chequeo de las cadenas las realice utilizando *slicing* sobre una lista. Las demás variables declaradas son una ayuda para no realizar una búsqueda en lugares incorrectos, otras para ayudar al *slicing* de la lista (start:stop:step) y la variable `total` que ayuda a saber si ya encontré las secuencias buscadas de cadenas

````
def check_automatizer(lista):
    
    A,T,C,G = 'AAAA', 'TTTT', 'CCCC', 'GGGG'
    c_d_d, c_d_i, c_h = 0, 0, 0 #Contador para chequeo
    v_d_d = round(len(lista) ** 0.5) + 1 #Variable de salto para diagonal derecha
    v_d_i = v_d_d - 2 #Variable de salto para diagonal izquierda
    v_v = v_d_d - 1 #Variable de salto para chequeo vertical
    c_dd_s = round((len(lista)**0.5)) * 4 #Stop de saltos para chequeo de diagonal derecho
    c_di_s = round((len(lista)**0.5)) * 3 #Stop de saltos para chequeo diagonal izquierdo
    c_v_s = c_dd_s #Stop de saltos para chequeo vertical
    c_h_s = 4 #Stop de saltos para chequeo horizontal
    val_if = round((len(lista)**0.5)) - 3 #Variable que me permite no leer lugares que no corresponden dependiendo el chequeo
    val_if_no_diags_and_verticals = (round(len(lista)**0.5) - 3) * round(len(lista)**0.5) #Variable que me permite no leer lugares que no corresponden dependiendo el chequeo
    val_if_last_value_row = round(len(lista) ** 0.5) - 1 #Variable que me permite no leer lugares que no corresponden dependiendo el chequeo
    total = 0 #Contador de mutantes
    for i in range(0, len(lista)-3): #n

        if c_d_d < val_if and i < val_if_no_diags_and_verticals and \
           lista[i:c_dd_s:v_d_d] == A or lista[i:c_dd_s:v_d_d] == T or lista[i:c_dd_s:v_d_d] == C or \
           lista[i:c_dd_s:v_d_d] == G: #Chequeo a traves de slicing de listas
                total += 1
        
        if c_d_i >= 3 and i < val_if_no_diags_and_verticals and \
           lista[i:c_di_s:v_d_i] == A or lista[i:c_di_s:v_d_i] == T or lista[i:c_di_s:v_d_i] == C or \
           lista[i:c_di_s:v_d_i] == G:
                total += 1
        
        if c_h < val_if and \
           lista[i:c_h_s:1] == A or lista[i:c_h_s:1] == T or lista[i:c_h_s:1] == C or \
           lista[i:c_h_s:1] == G:
            total += 1

        if i < val_if_no_diags_and_verticals and \
           lista[i:c_v_s:v_v] == A or lista[i:c_v_s:v_v] == T or lista[i:c_v_s:v_v] == C or \
           lista[i:c_v_s:v_v] == G:
            total += 1

        if c_h == val_if_last_value_row and c_d_d == val_if_last_value_row \
           and c_d_i == val_if_last_value_row:
            c_h = -1 #1
            c_d_d = -1
            c_d_i = -1
        if total >= 2:
            return (True, total)
        c_dd_s +=1
        c_di_s += 1
        c_h_s += 1
        c_v_s += 1
        c_d_d += 1
        c_d_i += 1 
        c_h += 1
        
    return (False, total)```
````

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: ¿Cual sería la *diagonal* de una lista?

Comment: La _complejidad algorítima_ es una medida de la escalabilidad del algoritmo. ¿Acaso hacen más comprobaciones cada uno de los ifs si aumenta el número de elementos de la matriz?

Comment: La complejidad algorítimca aumenta básicamente con los bucles, tanto si son explícitos (for) como si son implícitos (recursividad, comprensión de listas o búsquedas en arrays). Así que depende de lo que hagas en el `if`. Si por ejemplo tienes un `if elemento in lista` esa condición implícitamente es un bucle, ya que para saber si el elemento está o no en la lista hay que recorrerla. En tu caso en cambio los `if` no contienen bucles que yo vea, por lo que su complejidad es O(1) (el número de operaciones no depende de la cantidad de datos)